# Want to use input from index.php in name.php

Tags: php, function, loops, post, methods

Taking input from user for number of players in index.php

```html
<html>
<body>
  <form action="welcome.php" ; method="post">
    Enter number of players : <input type="number" name="players"> \\Selecting number of players
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<html>
<body>
  <?php $p=$_REQUEST['players']; echo $p;?>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br> So we have
  <?php echo $_POST["players"]; ?> players playing today!<br>
  <br>
  <form action="name.php" method="post">
    <?php 
for($i=1;$i<=$_POST["players"];$i++):?> Player
    <?php echo $i;?> name:<input type="text" name="<?php echo $i;?>"> <br>
    <?php endfor;?>
    <input type="submit">
</body>
</html>
```

```
<html>
<br>
<?php
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++): <--Instead of $i<=10 I want to use the number of players from index.php -->
echo "Name :".$_POST[$i];//can I use $_POST['players']
?>
  <input type="submit">
  <br>
  <?php endfor; ?>
</html>
```

I am receiving error if I use POST method may be because value is from index.php, and name.php has no connection with it.

Comment: `action="welcome.php" ;` < that semi-colon needs to be removed.

Comment: You didn't close off your form. Plus, your 2nd body of code has no form, so you can't use that input or POSTs.

Comment: You will also be receiving errors on initial page load, but you're not checking for errors.

Comment: My only question is that I want to use the number of players in for loop of name.php. How do I do that?